# Android media player not playing RTSP link Errror error (100, 0) E/MediaPlayer( 1170): Error (100,0)

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I'm trying to play RTSP link in micromax tablet android version 4.0.3,kernel version-3.0.8+inet-soft@inet#1.Same link is playing in another phone(like lava and Dell)but in micromax tab when we want to play it throws error.........

**Code:**

```
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
```

**Error:**

```
W/AudioSystem( 1170): AudioFlinger server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 1170): media server died
E/MediaPlayer( 1170): error (100, 0)
E/MediaPlayer( 1170): Error (100,0)
D/VideoView( 1170): Error: 100,0
W/IMediaDeathNotifier(  145): media server died
I/ServiceManager(   80): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   80): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   80): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(   80): service 'media.audio_policy' died
W/AudioSystem(  145): AudioFlinger server died!
W/AudioSystem(  145): AudioPolicyService server died!
I/ServiceManager(  145): Waiting for service media.player...
```

Comment: put some code where you getting error so community can understand where you going wrong and you will get answer asap

Comment: I haave updated my question please have look................

Comment: Yeah @AB1209 Actually in my case there was some server issue

Comment: @Dipu Can you please tell me what was the issue & how did you solve it.

Comment: @Dipu I am using NanaHTTPD class that create a custom HTTP server on my Android device.I am streaming from my custom server & on using it I am getting error.Please help me if you can.

Comment: Actually we use wowza for live streaming